# delete header and footer with my page gestion-projet

Tags: angular8

I want to delete header, footer and preloader in my page gestion-projet i use location in my code but it not works i have error when i inject the id what is the good syntax?

app.component.html

```
    <app-preloader *ngIf="!(location == '/auth'|| location=='/dashbord'|| location == '/gestion-employee' 
        || location =='/update-projet/:id')"></app-preloader>
       <app-header *ngIf="!(location == '/update-projet/:id' || location == '/coming-soon' || location == 
       '/gestion-employee' ||  location == '/not-found' || location =='/auth' ||location=='/dashbord')"> 
       </app-header>
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
         <app-footer *ngIf="!(location == '/update-projet/:id' || location == '/coming-soon' || location == 
         '/gestion-employee' || location == '/not-found' || location == '/auth'|| location=='/dashbord')"> 
        </app-footer>
```

Comment: How do you update `location` in ts file?

Comment: Also did you try with `!(location == '/auth' && location=='/dashbord' && location == '/gestion-employee' && location =='/update-projet/:id')` ? I think this should be the problem. When you do or operation and take negation as common out, you have to convert `||` to `&&`

Comment: Also It would be better if do this in `ts` file. As it will be easy to debug. Also each time angular recompiles template, it will have less task to do

Comment: the error is in the injection of id in link of "gestion-project /: id" and the other link are well to execute.the error is in syntaxe of injection id.

Comment: You can't test for `/:id`.... For that you have to check with `indexOf`... I have updated my answer below

Comment: that problem resolved in the page and i have an other error in console of browser "Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined"

Comment: that means `location` is undefined. Can you show us how are you assigning `location`?

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to do this kind of operations in `ts` file. It will be easy to debug and less work for angular when recompiling template.

Also consider following example

```
if (a != b || c != d)
```

If you want to take negation out as common then your `||` should have to convert to `&&`

Like

```
if (!( a == b && c == d))
```

I think you did mistake here.

And you can do this is ts like

```
showPreloader = !(location == '/auth' && location=='/dashbord' && location == '/gestion-employee') && location.indexOf('/update-projet/') > -1);

showHeaderFooter = !(location.indexOf('/update-projet/') > -1 && location == '/coming-soon' && location == '/gestion-employee' &&  location == '/not-found' && location =='/auth' && location=='/dashbord')
```

Then your template will become like this

```
<app-preloader *ngIf="showPreloader"></app-preloader>
<app-header *ngIf="showHeaderFooter"></app-header>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<app-footer *ngIf="showHeaderFooter"></app-footer>
```

Also make sure you are updating these booleans after every route change

Comment: I change || by && and it is not market the header and the footer are still appearing

Comment: Did you debug it? I mean you can check boolean values if they are present in ts file. You will come to know where you are doing mistake

Answer (score 0):

my file app.component.ts

```
`
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, NavigationStart, NavigationCancel, NavigationEnd } 
from'@angular/router';
import { Location, LocationStrategy, PathLocationStrategy } from 
     '@angular/common';
import { filter } from 'rxjs/operators';
     declare let $: any;
      @Component({
selector: 'app-root',
templateUrl: './app.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
providers: [
    Location, {
        provide: LocationStrategy,
        useClass: PathLocationStrategy
    }
]
          })
      export class AppComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
location: any;
routerSubscription: any;


constructor(private router: Router) {
}

ngOnInit() {
    this.recallJsFuntions();
}

recallJsFuntions() {
    this.router.events
        .subscribe((event) => {
            if ( event instanceof NavigationStart ) {
                $('.preloader').fadeIn('slow');
            }
        });
    this.routerSubscription = this.router.events
        .pipe(filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd || event instanceof NavigationCancel))
        .subscribe(event => {
            $.getScript('../assets/js/custom.js');
            $('.preloader').fadeOut('slow');
            this.location = this.router.url;
            console.log(location);
            if (!(event instanceof NavigationEnd)) {
                return;
            }
            window.scrollTo(0, 0);
        });
}

ngOnDestroy() {
    this.routerSubscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

}
`

Comment: where is `location.indexOf` ?

Comment: Did you write it in `html` file?